# Clojure: how to use compare with set/union

Tags: clojure, set, compare, comparator, set-union

For the sake of example, let's assume I have two sets:

```
(def set-a #{{:id 1 :name "ABC" :zip 78759} {:id 2 :name "DEF" :zip 78759}})

(def set-b #{{:id 1 :name "ABC" :zip 78753} {:id 3 :name "XYZ" :zip 78704}})
```

I would like to find an union between the sets, using only :id and :name fields. However, with out using a custom comparator I get four elements in the set, because :zip field is different.

```
(clojure.set/union set-a set-b)

#{{:id 3, :name "XYZ", :zip 78704} {:id 1, :name "ABC", :zip 78753}
  {:id 1, :name "ABC", :zip 78759} {:id 2, :name "DEF", :zip 78759}}
```

What is the idomatic way of finding union between two sets using a custom comparator or compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `group-by` to do this:

```
(map first (vals (group-by (juxt :id :name) (concat set-a set-b))))
```

Or threaded:

```
(->> (concat set-a set-b)
     (group-by (juxt :id :name))
     (vals)
     (map first))
```

This is grouping your elements by a combination of their key/values i.e. `(juxt :id :name)`. Then it grabs the `val`ues of the produced map, then `map`s `first` over that to get the first item in each grouping.

Or use some code specifically built for this like [`distinct-by`](https://github.com/weavejester/medley/blob/65a6925f6decda20a7eae7f2b9847d6ae3c75164/src/medley/core.cljc#L177).

Note these approaches apply to any collection, not just sets.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I was too concerned about solving the problem via union, that I missed this oblivious solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind throwing :zip away entirely, consider using clojure.set/project.

```
(clojure.set/union
 (clojure.set/project set-a [:id :name])
 (clojure.set/project set-b [:id :name]))

#{{:id 3, :name "XYZ"} {:id 2, :name "DEF"} {:id 1, :name "ABC"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I should have been more specific in my question, I do need :zip as well. However, I did learn something new from you regarding the clojure.set/project.